# Vertica performance on select from view with union

Tags: performance, select, vertica, query-performance

We have a huge number of rows(tens of millions), and for each table we have an associated view that is a select with UNION ALL between that table and several others.

Now, we are doing a select from that view with some conditions(where).
On Oracle and SQL Server the performance of the select is reasonable.
We have given a try to Vertica, because it is supposed to be good with selects on large tables, but the performance of this particular select is really bad.

I understand that when you do a union you lose the indexes on columns, because you can't get back to them.

What do you think is the problem with Vertica, is it missing some optimization steps that the other databases do ?

Comment: One for @kermit

Comment: Well, Vertica doesn't have indexes. The only sensible approach is for us to see the actual (anonymized) query.

Answer (score 1):

Vertica query performance depends highly on the predicate used in the query .

To get the gist of your performance , try getting the `projection name` of the selected columns of the query you are firing . The columns in the `order by` clause of the projection is very important in deciding the performance of your `select`. you can get that by running `explain` on your query .

Vertica improves performance by `sorting` the columns , `compressing` via `encoding` them so that they use minimal memory while running .

Also run `analyze_histogram(tablename, 100)` on all your tables . this will ensure statistics over complete data sample, not just 10% of data sample which is taken by `analyze_statistics` .

Also , since you are doing `union` you should try to keep the `sort order` of all the `projections` same as after `union` it might be meaningless .